# WPF Window with different DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have to do a task hard for me and maybe you can help me. I try to design a window dialog to update data from a database view. This database view contains integer, DateTime, string, Time, Boolean properties.

First of all, I load the database view data into a GridControl. The GridControl is readonly not editable. I configure the columns of my GridControl dynamically and this configuration is located in a database table called FieldDescription.

When the end-user doubleclicks on a cell, this window dialog pops up. This dialog shows a Combobox when the type of the column is enum or bit (boolean) and otherwise a TextEdit as default content.Notice for example that I know that a GridColumn represents an enum type because of the FieldDescription. Because the type of this database view property bound to this GridColumn is an integer (specifically the value)

The code of this window dialog is (I use DevExpress controls):

```
    <!-- DataTemplates -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
        <dxe:TextEdit Name="TxtNewValue" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      Text="{Binding TargetValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      Mask="{Binding TargetFieldDescription.fdValidateExp}" 
                      Loaded="FocusTextEditOnLoad"/>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.Date}">
                <Setter TargetName="TxtNewValue" Property="MaskType" Value="DateTime" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.DatTime}">
                <Setter TargetName="TxtNewValue" Property="MaskType" Value="DateTime" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.Time}">
                <Setter TargetName="TxtNewValue" Property="MaskType" Value="RegEx" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.Num}">
                <Setter TargetName="TxtNewValue" Property="MaskType" Value="RegEx" />
            </DataTrigger>                
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>

    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboboxTemplate">
        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding EnumItemsSource}" 
                          DisplayMember="Name"
                          ValueMember="Id"
                          IsTextEditable="False"
                          EditValue="{Binding TargetValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- Select a Datatemplate depending on the type of the Enum FieldDataType-->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type massedit:SimpleFieldVM}">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding .}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <!-- Without selector, only with DataTriggers select my ContentControl -->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.ENum}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ComboboxTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.Bit}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ComboboxTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<!-- Layout -->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Name="MainLayout" Content="{Binding}" />
</Grid>
```

I have only one ViewModel to provide the values to this Dialog Window. My ViewModel has an enum FieldDataType property called TargetFieldType. It contains the type of the doubleclicked GridColumn. This value is an Enum (FieldDataType.DatTime, FieldDataType.Time, FieldDataType.Date, FieldDataType.Bit, FieldDataType.Num, FieldDataType.Enum, FieldDataType.String).

The ItemsSource of the Combobox is bound with the ViewModel property:
    public List EnumItemsSource

Depending on the type of the column I prepare the data and I convert an enum of my model, in List, a boolean property also in List(Yes, No). But my ViewModel have to prepare the data depending on the FieldDataType. Maybe I can more things in the xaml code to save a lot of code to prepare the provided data to my view...or separating in more ViewModels my current ViewModel, to do this clearly.

It is difficult to explain the whole task but maybe you can help and tell me if my approach is correct or too difficult. I hope,you understand what I mean. Ask the questions that are needed.

Thanks